# Possibility to handle HTTPS connections by retrying failed ones via proxy, solve occational "connect: connection refused"

Tags: linux, proxy, shell

Sometimes I receive this error:

```
Error: Get "https://example.com/etc/etc": dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

The connection fails occasionally. When I try again, it works.

Is it possible to use local proxy server and set that server with `export https_proxy=` so that proxy retries more times or struggles more?

So the goal is that via this proxy server, I receive better quality - no occasionally failed requests. Waiting for longer is fine, the goal is not to get `connection refused` at proxy client side.

If this is possible, what proxy product should I use and how it should be configured?

Thanks

Comment: "squid retry attempt" in a search engine gave: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/connect_retries/

Comment: Thanks, I've tried Squid today and unfortunately, this parameter didn't help. I see this line in logs `172.22.0.1 NONE_NONE/503 0 CONNECT example.com:443/etc/etc - HIER_DIRECT/10.0.0.1 -` when proxy client fails.